# Extracting a part of a URL path

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6

I have a string like the one below from which I am extracting the tariff name.

`const url = "https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"`

So from the above string, I want text `tariffSelectionG_E5449168` and I am using the code below at the moment, which is working fine.

```
const supplyUrl = "https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"
  if(supplyUrl.includes('?')) {
    const url = supplyUrl.split('?')
    if(url.length > 0) {
      const tariff = url[0].split('supplier/')
      return tariff[1]
    }
  }
```

Is there any better way to do the above extracting?

Comment: You could leverage named capturegroups like `re = /https.*?supplier\/(?<param>.*)\?/g; re.exec(supplyUrl).groups["param"]` to retrieve the same result more compact.

Comment: If your environment supports it, you could use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it may be unlikely to occur, the URL *could* contain a hostname with a top-level domain `supplier`. Currently [`.supplies` is registered to Donuts Inc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#S) and someday URLs could have a TLD with `supplier`, which would lead the current code to not correctly find the target text.

```js
const supplyUrl = "https://my.supplier/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"
  if(supplyUrl.includes('?')) {
    const url = supplyUrl.split('?')
    if(url.length > 0) {
      const tariff = url[0].split('supplier/')
      console.log('tariff:', tariff[1])
    }
  }
```

A more robust solution would use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) with the [pathname property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname). For example, if it was known that the last part of the pathname was the tariff string then the array method [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) could be used:

```js
const supplyUrl = "https://my.supplier/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"
console.log('tariff: ', new URL(supplyUrl).pathname.split(/\//).pop());
```

Otherwise if there is a need to find strings anywhere in the path that start with `tariff` then a pattern match could be used for that - for example:

```js
const supplyUrl = "https://my.supplier/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"
function findTariff(url) {
    const pathParts = new URL(url).pathname.split(/\//);
    for (const part of pathParts) {
        if (part.match(/^tariff/)) {
            return part;
        }
    }
    return -1; // or something to signify not found
}
console.log('tariff: ', findTariff(supplyUrl));
```

Or one could take a functional approach, which can be more concise:

```js
const supplyUrl = "https://my.supplier/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"
function findTariff(url) {
    const pathParts = new URL(url).pathname.split(/\//);
    return pathParts.find(part => part.match(/^tariff/));
}
console.log('tariff: ', findTariff(supplyUrl));
```

Answer (score 5):

Super short review;

- The code should handle the presence or the absence `?` in a transparent way
- The code should probably check for `/supplier/` instead of `?`

That leaves me with

```
function extractTariffName(url){
  const resource = '/supplier/';
  if(url.contains(resource)){
    return url.split('?').shift().split(resource).pop();
  }
  //return undefined
}

console.log(extractTariffName('https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars'));
console.log(extractTariffName('https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168'));
console.log(extractTariffName('https://any-api/supliar/tariffSelectionG_E5449168'));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think for any url related task you have two good tools as

1. The [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
2. The [URLPattern API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_Pattern_API)

With the `URL` constructor you may do like;

```
var url        = new URL("https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"),
    tariffCode = url.pathname.slice(url.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

`URLPattern` API, on the other hand is more powerful and convenient for this job despite being a little comprehensive. Keep in mind that it's a recent API and available in Chrome 95+. Server side, it is available in [Deno](https://deno.land/) (*which i like very much*) and possibly in recent Node versions too.

In this particular case we can generate an URL Pattern which takes the path up until a variable that we declare. This variable represents the url portion of our interest. Lets name it `tariff`. Accordingly

```
var pat = new URLPattern({pathname: "/supplier/:tariff"});
```

Thats it.

Once you receive an url first you can test it's validity against the pattern like;

```
pat.test("https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars"); // <- true
```

If `true` then you can extract your tariff code like

```
var tariffCode = pat.exec("https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars")
                    .pathname.groups.tariff; // <- "tariffSelectionG_E5449168"
```

Comment: Reminder: the `URLPattern` API is still experimental in 2023 and not implemented in Mozilla Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use the `URL` constructor. It is a bit clearer semantically:

```
const supplyUrl = new URL("https://any-api/supplier/tariffSelectionG_E5449168?t=randomChars");
const parts = supplyUrl.pathname.split("/");

// the 0th item is empty since the pathname starts with a slash
const tariff = parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get text before '?' with `split('?').at()`,
then reverse it and get text before '/'
and reverse it back ;)
`supplyUrl.split('?').at().split('').reverse().join('').split('/').at().split('').reverse().join('')`